# How to avoid casting a DOM element to any in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, dom

I am getting the value of a DOM element with Typescript this way:

```
(<any>document.getElementById('MyElementId')).value
```

It does not seem right to cast it to `any`. Is there a way to use types to get this attribute?

Comment: Did you try this code without specifying type? Is it working?

Comment: It gives me a compile time error

Comment: Good question. Please avoid "right way to X" question as they invite opinionated answers. I rephrased your question as it appears your goal is to get rid of the any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know the specific type of element you are getting? If so, you can use the built in element types instead of casting to `any`. There is a built in type for all the basic DOM element types (div, anchor, span, option, etc.).

For example, if you're getting, say, a textarea element, you can do:

```
(<HTMLTextAreaElement>document.getElementById('MyElementId')).value
```

The `getElementById` function returns just a plain `Element`, since there's no way typescript can know what type of element will be returned (if any is returned at all). But since all the more specific element types (`HTMLOptionElement`, `HTMLTextAreaElement`, etc.) are all subtypes of `Element`, you can narrow your return type with a cast to get that type safety you're looking for.

Comment: Perfect answer, do you know of an online resource that I could use to search this kind of stuff myself?

Comment: @ArturoHernandez The online resource you're looking for is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/. In particular, for this question, you'd want to take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element